# Ajax FilteredTextBox Extender is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I did everything correct and its not showing me any error. I just want to allow user to enter numbers but its allowing all the characters.
Here is my source

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" FilterType="Numbers">
        </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Phone No"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `ToolkitScriptManager` instead of a `ScriptManager`

You could also  try `ValidChars` instead of `FilterType`

```
<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" 
                             TargetControlID="TextBox1" ValidChars="0123456789.,">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use FilterMode="ValidChars" or FilterMode="InvalidChars". 
Then use the ValidChars="0123456789.," or InvalidChars="0123456789.," to do the job

```
<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender 
        ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" 
        runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
        FilterMode="ValidChars"
        ValidChars="0123456789.,">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```